# Convert the data, split rows into columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, transform, stuff

Could you please help me in displaying the table output in below format.

**Table data**
[image]

**Required output**
[image]

Comment: please include the DBMS and also, are these the only 5 countries in countryname or could be more?

Comment: Hi Jayvee, I am using SQL server 2014, and the countries could be more or less.

Comment: Search "dynamic pivot".

Comment: Thank you Jayvee and Larnu. Your inputs helped me to achieve the required output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.CountryName)
FROM #temptest c
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ObjectName, ' + @cols + ' from
(
select ObjectName,CountryName,counts
from #temptest
) x
pivot
(
max(counts)
for CountryName in (' + @cols + ')
) p '

execute(@query)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the exhaustive list of countries you have to include all of them in the query, if the list is dynamic then it's a problem and the only way would be by dynamic sql. Please try this and let us know:

```
SELECT
  ObjectName,
  CZ,HQ,RO,BR,SK
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM yourtable
) AS X
PIVOT
(
  SUM(counts)
  FOR CountryName
  IN (
    [CZ],[HQ],[RO],[BR],[SK]
  )
) AS PivotX
```

Comment: Thanks Jayvee, it is working. But I am looking for a dynamic query.